# How to add picture and text into popup marker in folium?

Tags: python, html, iframe, instagram-api, folium

I'm currently trying to show some picture from Instagram API and their location in folium. What I'm trying to do is show the position in folium and use popup marker to show the picture and the caption of the picture.

I managed to show the picture in the popup marker but I don't know how to add text with the picture.

This is my code:

```py
from InstagramAPI import InstagramAPI
from nested_lookup import nested_lookup
import folium
from folium import IFrame
import base64
import requests

image_url=[]

username="username"
InstagramAPI = InstagramAPI(username, "password")
InstagramAPI.login()

InstagramAPI.timelineFeed()
timelinefeed = InstagramAPI.LastJson

image_url_lookup=nested_lookup('candidates', timelinefeed)
for x in range(0,len(image_url_lookup)):
    image_url.append(image_url_lookup[x][1]['url'])

html = '<img src="data:image/JPG;base64,{}">'.format
m = folium.Map(location=[20, 0], tiles="Stamen Terrain", zoom_start=12)
encoded = base64.b64encode(requests.get(image_url[1]).content).decode()
iframe = IFrame(html(encoded), width=632+20, height=420+20)
popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=1000)
folium.Marker(location=[72, -40],popup=popup).add_to(m)
m.save("Map_Show.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add some text in your `html` variable:

```
html = '''<h3> This is a big popup</h3><br>
<img src="data:image/JPG;base64,{}"><br>
<p>foo bar</p>'''.format
```